# CIFS share hangs after a while

Tags: fstab, cifs

I have 2 VMs, one on Ubuntu 17.04 and one on Windows 10, between them I have a mounted folder to share files. This folder is mounted on Ubuntu with CIFS.
My setup was working great until 2-3 days but now when I boot Ubuntu the folder is correctly mounted and I can access the files on Windows via Ubuntu, but after a few minutes about half an our, when I try to access the folder or do a LS or anything that points to this folder, my terminal hangs and I can't do anything else.

Output of `syslog`:

```
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152349] INFO: task mount.cifs:9755 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152352]       Not tainted 4.4.0-75-generic #96-Ubuntu
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152353] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152355] mount.cifs      D ffff880135c3fbe8     0  9755      1 0x00000004
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152358]  ffff880135c3fbe8 ffff8801368fecb8 ffff880138688e00 ffff8800b65faa00
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152360]  ffff880135c40000 ffff8800ba19c624 ffff8800b65faa00 00000000ffffffff
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152361]  ffff8800ba19c628 ffff880135c3fc00 ffffffff81837845 ffff8800ba19c620
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152363] Call Trace:
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152368]  [<ffffffff81837845>] schedule+0x35/0x80
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152370]  [<ffffffff81837aee>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0xe/0x10
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152372]  [<ffffffff81839729>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0xb9/0x130
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152373]  [<ffffffff818397bf>] mutex_lock+0x1f/0x30
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152387]  [<ffffffffc02e9a8e>] cifs_get_smb_ses+0x22e/0x690 [cifs]
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152396]  [<ffffffffc02ea54b>] cifs_mount+0x65b/0xdc0 [cifs]
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152399]  [<ffffffff811f0ef4>] ? __kmalloc_track_caller+0x1b4/0x250
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152405]  [<ffffffffc02d58c8>] cifs_do_mount+0x118/0x5c0 [cifs]
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152408]  [<ffffffff811e2b1c>] ? alloc_pages_current+0x8c/0x110
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152410]  [<ffffffff81212e98>] mount_fs+0x38/0x160
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152412]  [<ffffffff8122f527>] vfs_kern_mount+0x67/0x110
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152414]  [<ffffffff81231bdf>] do_mount+0x25f/0xda0
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152416]  [<ffffffff81232a5f>] SyS_mount+0x9f/0x100
Apr 26 15:45:55 frontierland kernel: [ 6360.152418]  [<ffffffff8183b972>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
```

I am mounting the folder like this via FSTAB

```
//fantasyland/Media  /home/mickey/WindowsShare  cifs _netdev,credentials=/home/mickey/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,nosetuids,noperm  0  0
```

I did a test with a new installation of Ubuntu and still have the same issue... I am wondering if it's not a package that causes this problem but no idea which one..

I have no idea why this happened suddenly. 
Any clue on where I could look?

Thank you
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution, it is by adding vers=3.0 in the fstab mount as follow

//servershare /ShareMount cifs **vers=3.0**,credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,nosetuids, noperm 0 0

I have been testing this modification since 22hrs now and I am not experiencing any more disconnections.

Comment: I have the same issue and this parameter does not help :(

Comment: @sangorys try using different `vers`. SMB 2.0 was introduced by Vista/2008
SMB 2.1 by Win7/2008R2
SMB 2.2 aka 3.0 by Win8/2012
SMB 3.02 by 8.1/2012R2 . I tried using 2.1 on my server and it works.